# ADB Device Unauthorized - Locked out Samsung S9 - USB Debugging is On, but locked out of the verification pop-up

Tags: adb, locked-out, samsung-galaxy-s-9, authorization

I locked myself out of my Samsung Galaxy S9.  I genuinely just forgot my gesture swipe lock, and my phone must have restarted overnight, so I couldn't use my fingerprint.

- USB Debugging is On
- I have ADB up and running on my PC
- /adb devices brings back my phone as 'unauthorized'
- I cannot get through my lock screen, so I am unable to allow access on the pop-up on my phone.
- Phone is not rooted, no custom recovery

Hopefully someone can help, I really don't want to have to factory reset.

Comment: Not gonna happen that way, you're pretty much out of luck on the ADB side of things. Do you know the Google account on the phone? If so you should be able to recover it fairly easily., either through the device via the "forgot password" option, or from Google's Find My Phone (Lock the device via the web interface, then unlock with that PIN).

Comment: @acejavelin 

Yes the google account is mine, however, there is no option to unlock my phone with "Forgot Password" after I fail swipe. There is no option other than Emergency Call.

Google's Find My Device gives me 3 options, Play Sound, Secure Device, Erase Device.

Secure Device only Locks and Signs me out of my Device.  I have no option to send a temporary code or PIN.

And sadly, I did not know about Samsung's Unlock Remotely setting, so I can't unlock it through Samsung's Find My Phone

Is there something I'm doing incorrectly to not have the Google options available?

Comment: @acejavelin it wouldn't let me tag you, hopefully this works?

Comment: I think it's "Secure Device" option now... I haven't tried it in a long time, it's changed a lot. Seems to be less options than before. But once you enter your passcode wrong enough times, doesn't give an option to recover with Google Account?

Comment: and tagging works fine, it just doesn't highlight it like other forums. I got two notifications, was just working and couldn't get to it right away. :)

Comment: @acejavelin I used "Secure Device" before posting my question, I never got an option to put in a new or temporary Pin/Password.  All I was able to do was add an optional recovery message, and a phone number (which showed up on my phone as a button to call that number directly)

And no, I only have swipe and fingerprint turned on in my settings (prefer it over PIN, tho I'm regretting that now).  When I keep failing my swipe code, I just get locked out on a timer before I can try again.  Time started at 15 seconds, and then climbed to 30s, 1m, 2m, 4m, 8m, and now I'm at 16m between tries.

Comment: i am afraid google removed that feature, stupid